# Calling a method from Usercontrol xaml.cs to View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I am using MVVM in my project and I am implementing the Diagram Designer and I am using RAD Diagram control of Telerik.I am dragging the shape from my RadToolBox to canvas for which I have implemented the event.Now on this event I want to save the diagram in RavenDB once the shape has been dropped on Canvas ( Ruler).This whole thing is in the User control stored in one library and I am creating the reference of this library in my actual WPF form which is in other library.My requirement is I want to call the Save command which is present in View Model of WPF form, from my xaml.cs of the user control and this user control is present in other library.

How shall i achieve the same.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do have multiple assemblies? If you don't ***need*** them, then make your life simpler and just use NameSpaces to separate your controls from your forms in the same assembly.

Right now that's said :-)

The easy way is via an Event. Add an event to your `UserControl`, and then in the `Window` add the code when the event happens.

Have a read through [MSDN Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I really dont Why you would need to call a save command from another WindowsForm.
Telerik UI Diagram provides indefined save Command which is used to save the Diagram,
InXAML,

```
<Grid.CommandBindings>
                <CommandBinding Command="telerik:DiagramCommands.Save" Executed="ExecuteSave" />
</Grid.CommandBindings>
```

And In code behind define save function,

```
private void ExecuteSave(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            this.diagram.save();
        }
```